# Force the program to run minimized or in the tray (prevent maximized windows; not on startup)?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, window

There's a particular program/process (Mailbird Updater) that pops up a window from time to time (not on startup) notifying you about the new available updates. Those windows always appear maximized and focused and as a result minimize the currently running fullscreen programs and games. There's no "game mode" or anything like that to disable such activity, and the notifications cannot be disabled unless you disable update check. I would like to keep being informed about the updates, but is there any way to prevent the window/form from appearing in maximized view, instead minimized or hidden in the tray? Via 3rd party software or any other way?

Windows 7 and 10.

Comment: Mailbird is a commercial software you are paying for. Why not contact the customer support and demand a game mode?

Comment: @Robert I did, a year ago.

Comment: Does the updater only run when the main program is running or is it independent?

Comment: @Robert only when the main program is running, but as a separate process/executable.